# Regex to match Ipv4 with mask

Tags: regex

I am validating a Ipv4 address by a regex and it does not support subnet mask.

```
^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$
```

Can some one help me with the regex which supports mask as well.

Here is a working example of this regex: **[demo](http://www.regexr.com/3b4cg)**

Comment: Any sample input? What did you try?

Comment: what you have seems to work fine. matches 255.255.255.0, the most common subnet mask.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey. I would also include validation with slash. Could you help.

Comment: depends on the level of validation. You can tack (\/\d+)? to the end (before $), but it won't always make sense. It's tricky to know the real maximum because a subnet can really be quite a large number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `(?:/[0-2]\d|/3[0-2])?` at the end of your regex. You can also simplify the regex:

```
^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}(?:/[0-2]\d|/3[0-2])?$
```

Comment: There is a mistake in your regexp, it should be: `^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.[01]?\d\d?|\.2[0-4]\d|\.25[0-5]){3}(?:/[0-2]\d|/3[0-2])?$`. A valid IP `220.200.255.0/32` is matched by my regexp, but not by yours.

Comment: @niekas: Good catch, fixed.

Comment: This seems to fail for ```192.168.0.0/8``` But is valid for ```192.168.0.0/08```. How do we account for the optional single digit for the subnet mask?

Comment: @blueren: Change the last part into: `(?:/[0-2]?\d|/3[0-2])?`, `[0-2]` becomes optional `[0-2]?`

Comment: WARNING: this answer is wrong! It matches values like 001.01.01.01/09

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proper IPv4 subnet regex without any lookaheads that matches correct notation.

**Mask OPTIONAL Version:**

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/(3[0-2]|[1-2]?\d))?$
```

**Matched examples:**

- 0.0.0.0/0
- 255.255.255.255/32
- 100.70.60.50 *(This version supports no mask)*

**Rejected examples:**

- 001.01.01.01/09 *(matched by currently accepted answer)*
- 256.0.0.0/30 *(256 is out of range!)*
- 100.70.60.50/33 *(33 is out of bounds)*
- 100.70.60.50/ *(incomplete mask)*

**Mask REQUIRED Version:**
If you'd like a version that **requires** the mask, then use this instead:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\/(3[0-2]|[1-2]?\d)$
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if you want it to match both adresses, remove beginning ^ and trailing $