# Check if a string is a valid IPv4 subnet address with optional mask in CPP

Tags: c++, ipv4

I am trying to write a function in cpp that checks if a given string is a valid IP subnet with mask or not. Examples of valid input are "20.0.0.0/32", "20.0.0.0/2", etc.

I have seen questions and answers that use inet_pton to check if the string is IPv4. But I am not sure what I can use for IP subnet with masks.

Comment: Are you aiming just to see if the string is of the form "x.y.z.w/n", where x, y, z, w, and n are integers within a given range, or are there additional checks about what constitutes a valid subnet-mask that you also want to validate?

Comment: Yes @JeremyFriesner, I am looking for something like that in cpp

Comment: Sounds easy enough to me, what have you tried?

Comment: @PaulSanders I have mainly looked at inet library and their functions (e.g. inet_pton) but they seem to be without masks

Comment: @brokendreams -- Have you considered using a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590193/regex-to-match-ipv4-with-mask)?

Comment: Then when you get the regular expression correct, use `std::regex` or some C++ regular expression code if not `std::regex`.

Comment: @brokendreams Yes, they don't handle masks.  Just search the string for the `/` and go from there.  `std::find` would be a good start.  A regex is overkill for this, IMHO.